# When setting up a mixed effects model in R, how is the model applied to all variables specified by the loop?

Tags: r

I install a mixed effects model in R. But I want to apply this model to all numeric variables in my dataset with a single code. I wrote a code like the one below but got an error. What can I do?

My Data=df

```
# 200 x 20
   week      weight     height  .......
  <fct>      <dbl>      <dbl>     
1 week1       50.0       160        
2 week1       62.5       172     
3 week2       49.6       155     
4 week3       80.0       165     
5 week2       56.8       163     
6 week3       72.3       180    
.
.
.
.
```

Mixed effect model is set up for single variable as follows

```
mixed.model <- lmer( weight ~ 1 + (1|week), data = df)
a=ranova(mixed)
a$`Pr(>Chisq)`
```

The code I wrote to apply to multiple variables

```
for (i in 2:(dim(df)[2])){
  mixed.model <- lmer( i ~ 1 + (1|week), data = df)
}
```

The error i got

```
Error in model.frame.default(data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE, : variable lengths differ (found for 'week')
```

Comment: @DaveArmstrong is right, you can't just stick a symbol referencing a variable into a formula and expect it to work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably make a formula first and then pass the formula to the model function (Thanks to Ben Bolker for the tip on reformulate):

```
for (i in names(df)[-1]){
  form <- reformulate("1 + (1|week)", response=i)
  mixed.model <- lmer(form, data = df)
}
```

---

### EDIT

In response to the comment about always getting the first variable, here's what I get when I run the loop, each time printing the formula:

```
df <- data.frame(
  week = sample(1:3, 1000, replace=TRUE), 
  X1 = rnorm(1000), 
  X2 = rnorm(1000),
  X3 = rnorm(1000)
)

library(lme4)
for (i in names(df)[-1]){
  form <- reformulate("1 + (1|week)", response=i)
  print(form)
  # mixed.model <- lmer(form, data = df)
}

# X1 ~ 1 + (1 | week)
# X2 ~ 1 + (1 | week)
# X3 ~ 1 + (1 | week)
```

As you can see, there is a different formula for each iteration.

Comment: and as always consider `reformulate()` for a slightly cleaner design ...

Comment: also, I think you probably need `for (i in names(df)[-1])`

Comment: Thank you. But I got an error like this:
`Error in terms.formula (formula, data = data): invalid term in model formula`

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for your suggestion.  I added it in.  I have to admit that I didn't know about `reformulate()` before, but will definitely use it now.

Comment: @NurI I edited the answer to take advantage of Ben's suggestion.  Try it now.  If that doesn't work, you'll actually have to post some data for us to be able to help further.

Comment: @Nur can you post your data or another reproducible example?

Comment: @Nur if you want to save the results you have to store them somewhere, e.g. use `results <- list()` before you start the loop, then `results[[i]] <- lmer(...)` within the loop (this is all fundamental working-with-R stuff, nothing to do specifically with mixed models)